How to configure a kafka Schema registry client with ssl bundle
I'm looking for a way to configure a schema registry client by using a ssl bundle.
I have an application that sends messages to a kafka topic.
The producer is configured using keystore and trustore informations and everything is working fine.
Now, I need to switch the config to the use of ssl bundle.
I was able to configure the producer, however, i did not find a way to configure the schema registry client.
Is there a way to do this ?
in the application.yml file, I tried this:
spring.kafka.properties.schema.registry.url =  ........ spring.kafka.properties.schema.registry.ssl.bundle = theBundle
But the client could not connect to the registry.

Cannot be done. Schema registry (scala client) requires the cert to be available on the file system
